# Where is the private key stored for an IIS CSR request?

Tags: windows, iis

My understanding is, that the certificate signing request is generated from a private key. When I create a new CSR from IIS, only the CSR is exported to a text file. Where is the private key used for the CSR located?

Comment: https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/628/19/csr-generation-microsoft-iis-7x "To save your private key"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. From your server, go to Start > Run and enter mmc in the text box. Click on the OK button.
2. From the Microsoft Management Console (MMC) menu bar, select Console > Add/Remove Snap-in.
3. Click on the Add button. Select Certificates from the list of snap-ins and then click on the Add button.
4. Select the Computer account option. Click on the Next button.
5. Select the Local computer (the computer this console is running on) option. Click on the Finish button.
6. Click on the Close  button on the snap-in list window. Click on the OK button on the Add/Remove Snap-in window.
7. Click on Certificates from the left pane. Look for a folder called REQUEST or "Certificate Enrollment Request> Certificates
   Select the private key that you wish to backup.
8. Select the private key that you wish to get.

More information you can refer to this link: [Using Microsoft IIS to generate CSR and Private Key](https://docs.druva.com/Knowledge_Base/inSync/How_To/Using_Microsoft_IIS_to_generate_CSR_and_Private_Key).

Comment: Last year I generated a CSR and had it signed...   This year I had to do it again, obviously.  Both PFX files appear to be using the SAME public key. I followed the same steps for a CSR generation both times, and would expect a new private key to be generated.   How/Why did that happen?

Comment: This really didn't answer the question because after following all the steps here, you still don't know the path to that file which was the question being asked. You only see it in a panel in that app. Clicking on the panel item makes a window pops up with some tabs and info but no path to where that file might be.  You can export a copy of the certificate, but that's as good as it gets. Anyone know the real answer?